# MODx Revo ускорение

Tags: modx, веб-программирование, оптимизация, revo

**Вопрос про ускорение и оптимизацию. Сейчас у меня сайт близится к окончанию на Modx revo.** Но страницы бывает подгружаются по 5-6 секунд, если без кеширования, с кешированием за 2 сек. Посещения - 0. Ресурсов штук 30. Использовал стандартные снипеты. Но не могу понять, почему сайт может так тормозить даже без продакшна. Писал сайт на EVO, летает, даже быстрее того когда на рево включен кэш. Может из-за того что я использовал там самописные сниппеты? Есть ли какая - нибудь волшебнная кнопка, которая позволит увеличить скорость сайта в несколько раз? (извиняюсь за детский сад))

Понимаю, нужно продумывать ускорение на месте в каждом случае по разному. Но все таки ожидаешь от нового движка с новостным сайтом, что он не будет так тупить без особой нагрузки, даже с учетом мелких допущенных ошибок в коде

Answer (score 1):

`"Использовал стандартные снипеты"` - стандартные снппеты ооочень медленные. Хочешь скорости - используй `pdoTools`. Ну и `pthumb` вместо phpthumbof. Для 90% случаев - этого хватает за глаза, если нет - ищи сниппеты которые тормозят и разбирайся конкретно с ними.

Answer (score 1):

Есть некоторые проблемы со скоростью, соглашусь и с Vasis.

> стандартные сниппеты ооочень медленные

1. Мне помог переезд БД на SSD. Значительно ускорилась работа. Требует вложений в хостинг.
2. Как более дешевый, но трудноватый вариант — установить кеширующий nginx

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь проверь, не вызываются ли у тебя сниппеты рекурсивно (getResources для списка новостей -> getResources в чанке каждой новости и тд).

После проверь, нет ли у тебя явного указания НЕ КЭШИРОВАТЬ вывод сниппетов ( например: [[!getResources]] ). Запрещать кэширование можно только в случаях, которые действительно этого требуют.

Поменьше используй всяких стандартных сниппетов наподобие [[If]]

Не стреляй из пушки по воробьям :) Если нужна какая-то простая операция от сложного сниппета (вырожденный пример - использовать getResources для получения и вывода TV у товара) - вынеси этот функционал в свой сниппет.

Ну и наконец, попробуй перенести чанки и сниппеты из базы на диск. По умолчанию, они находятся в базе.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно реальное ускорение, надо забыть про if is then else - т.е. убери всю логику, сделанную на этом сниппете IF.
На соседнем ресурсе разогрелась нешуточная война двух лагерей, суть в том, что ModX, встретив такие обертки, сначала обрабатывает все вложенные сниппеты и затем уже проверяет условие!!
Т.е. как бы это не звучало консервативно, все-таки для очень разных страниц правильнее использовать разные шаблоны! А не так, как некоторые хвастаются - "У меня ОДИН шаблон на всё про всё!" )))

Comment: И еще - вызов одного сниппета один раз на странице! Порой смотришь и давишься слезами)), как в том же Минишопе2 люди выводят товары на странице категории, вызывая в чанке сниппет получения опции, КАЖДЫЙ раз для каждого товара!!)) Причем это штатный шаблон! ну понятно, почему он такой, этот шаблон))))

Answer (score 0):

есть готовый [кэширующий плагин для ускорения сайта](https://webdevops.ru/blog/extra-cache-plugin-modx.html) gitHub: [modxExtraCachePlugin](https://github.com/commeta/modxExtraCachePlugin) умеет кэшировать сессионные ключи от компонентов и прогревать кэш через wget